# Does the link function require passing parameters

Tags: angularjs

If using the `link:` for a custom angularjs search directive, do I need to pass parameters and `$scope`?

The search directive just needs to perform autocomplete (using AngularUI Typeahead for that) and search functions. I already have a controller but am asking if using a link function in the directive might be because I would like to avoid using attributes to pass parameters in the element directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link: is used to register DOM listeners or update the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned. It is where directive logic is written.

link takes a function with the following signature:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }
```

you can omit these parameters if you don't need one. But, if you need any one, you need to place them at the appropriate location as described in the syntax.

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would need the link function at all especially if you already are using a controller. Can we get some more information on what functionality you are adding in addition to that being provided by UI-bootstrap typeahead?

Comment: @Christian, this is more of a comment about the question - not an answer - as already stated in the question, just autocomplete and search functions